# QT. Is any way to multiplicate string several times?

Tags: string, qt

In python i can write

```
s = "dad" * 3
```

Result will be: s = "daddaddad"

I want to append "tabs" to my string. Something like:

```
QString tabs = "\t" * count;
```

What would be a simple, idiomatic way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it quite simply with a loop:

```
QString mystring("somestring");
QString output;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    output.append(mystring);
//'output' will contain the result string
```

Please note that the code I provide is in C++, not Python, but the concept still applies (and should be easily ported).

**EDIT**:
If you need to concatenate single characters, you could do it more easily like this:

```
int size = 5;
QString output(size, QChar('\t'));
//'output' contains 5 tab characters
```

Or, if you need to assign to another string (`output` is already created):

```
int size = 5;
output.fill(QChar('\t'), size);
//'output' contains 5 tab characters
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <QString>
QString s;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    s << "dad";
}
```